# Connect component to redux and multiple libraries during export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm not sure if I have phrased the question correctly, but here is an issue. I am using [react drag and drop library](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd) where my export class looks like this:

```
module.exports = DropTarget(dragTypes, storyTarget, collect)(MyClassName);
```

I also need to connect this component to redux, which would look like this:

```
module.exports = connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyClassName)
```

And I have no idea how to create correct export to satisfy both of these needs.

This is using ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
const DropComponent = DropTarget(dragTypes, storyTarget, collect)(MyClassName);
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DropComponent);
```